# Subsetting from a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a list of dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1:5), c(6:10))
df2 <- data.frame(c(1:7))
df3 <- data.frame(c(1:5), c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

From my_list, I want to extract the data frames which have only 2 columns (df1 and df3), and put them in a new list.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try `lengths`

```
> my_list[lengths(my_list) == 2]
[[1]]
  c.1.5. c.6.10.
1      1       6
2      2       7
3      3       8
4      4       9
5      5      10

[[2]]
  c.1.5. c..a....b....c....d....e..
1      1                          a
2      2                          b
3      3                          c
4      4                          d
5      5                          e
```

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to subset using `lapply` and a logical condition (`sapply` will also work):

```
my_list[lapply(my_list, ncol) == 2]
```

```
[[1]]
  c.1.5. c.6.10.
1      1       6
2      2       7
3      3       8
4      4       9
5      5      10

[[2]]
  c.1.5. c..a....b....c....d....e..
1      1                          a
2      2                          b
3      3                          c
4      4                          d
5      5                          e
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `keep` from `purrr` package with the condition:

```
library(purrr)
my_list %>% keep(~ ncol(.x) == 2)
```

```
[[1]]
  c.1.5. c.6.10.
1      1       6
2      2       7
3      3       8
4      4       9
5      5      10

[[2]]
  c.1.5. c..a....b....c....d....e..
1      1                          a
2      2                          b
3      3                          c
4      4                          d
5      5                          e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Filter`

```
has2colums <- function(df) ncol(df) == 2
my_list |> Filter(f = has2colums)
```

In one line `my_list |> Filter(f = \(df) ncol(df) == 2)`